# Move an item up/down a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the order of things in a select control without having to totally rebuild it?

Is there a javascript function where I can change the "index" of a specific option in the select?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just find the two elements in jQuery (by their IDs or whatever), so you have two objects and then use `before()` on them

```
var o1=$("#opt1");
var o2=$("#opt2");
o2.insertBefore(o1);
```

Comment: I like your solution better than mine. Why didn't I think of that? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Array.splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

```
// Remove the option from the list:
var option = selectElement.options.splice(indexOfOptionToRemove,1);

// and put it back in at the new index:
selectElement.options.splice(indexOfNewOptionPosition,option);
```